# Issue with variable-declaration

Tags: apex-variable

I have this string 'SELECT Id,Account,(SELECT field1, field2....
Further on I declare a for-loop with 2 variables:
for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {

```
               Id AccId = opp.AccountId;
               Id AccIdCoAppl = opp.field2;
```

The AccId-variable compiles nicely and the code executes nicely as well.
BUT when I declare the 2nd variable I get the error Variable does not exist: field2
I'am a beginner in Apex and simply don't understand why this is an error

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange. You'll need to post a bit more of your code to enable anyone to help you. E.g. the full SOQL query. It looks like 'field2' doesn't exist with that API name on Opportunity. Maybe you could also post the real API names  in your code so we can check those as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should re-phrase the question

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly access the inner query field. please follow the below

```
List<Account> accountsWithContacts = [
    SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
];

for (Account acc : accountsWithContacts) {
    System.debug('Account Name: ' + acc.Name);
    
    for (Contact con : acc.Contacts) {
        System.debug('Contact Name: ' + con.FirstName + ' ' + con.LastName);
        System.debug('Contact Email: ' + con.Email);
    }
    
    System.debug('-------------------------');
}
```

for custom objects you can follow this

```
List<Custom_Object__c> customObjectsWithRelated = [
    SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Related_Field__c FROM Related_Custom_Object__r)
    FROM Custom_Object__c
];

for (Custom_Object__c customObj : customObjectsWithRelated) {
    System.debug('Custom Object Name: ' + customObj.Name);
    
    for (Related_Custom_Object__c relatedObj : customObj.Related_Custom_Object__r) {
        System.debug('Related Object Field: ' + relatedObj.Related_Field__c);
    }
    
    System.debug('-------------------------');
}
```